# echo to standard input or stdin

Tags: shell, unix

How can I echo to stdin?

For example, I have an alias called 'replace'. When I run 'replace' it should echo

```
sed 's/~/~\\n/g'
```

into my command line. Notice the sed command above doesn't have a file target. I'll supply the file target after it echos the sed into the command line.

Comment: Standard input of what? To send the standard output of one command to the standard input of another, use a pipe: `command1 | command2`

Comment: This question is confusing.  You want to display the alias before executing it.  You should probably write a function that will allow you to specify the file target but if you type the `sed` command as is, it will expect the input to be typed on `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `alias` like this:

```
alias replace="sed 's/~/~\\n/g' "
```

And then run it like this:

```
replace file
```

PS: It won't `echo` the full sed command on your tty but it will effectively run:

```
sed 's/~/~\\n/g' file
```

**EDIT:** On your question of echoing command before executing. Create a script `sedscript.sh` like this:

```
set -x
# do some sanity check on $1
sed 's/~/~\\n/g' "$1"
```

Now have you alias like this:

```
chmod +x sedscript.sh
alias replace="/path/to/sedscript.sh "
```

Now every time you run:

```
replace file
```

It will echo this line before sed command execution:

```
++ sed 's/~/~\\n/g' file
```

Comment: yep, it works for what I need! but since it's already brought up, do you also know how to echo the sed command into stdin?

Comment: hey that's pretty cool. i tried it and it works. how did you manage to find that?